# Looping through array.xml

Tags: java, android

I have an array.xml file to store my arrays. All arrays contain five string values.
I create a random number and due to the random number I load the array from array.xml via a switch case. This works fine, but it is a lot of work to have array.xml and a switch case.
Is there a way to iterate through an array.xml file in android?
Something like this:

```
for array : array.xml{
randomPicture = new RandomPicture(array);
adapter.add(randomPicture)
}
```

best regards, nico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have a loop for values in a resource files like `xml`. But you could put all the values inside single array inside array.xml like

```
  <string-array name="condition">
    <item>no</item>
    <item>yes</item>
</string-array>
```

and get all the values like

```
String[] values =getResouces().getStringArray(R.array.condition)
```

and loop through obtained values.

Comment: ok, but this was what i was looking for , to loop over all array in a xml file. thanks

Answer (score 2):

you need to get the array from resources and then iterate over it.

```
String[] starry = Context.getResources().getStringArray(R.id.your_array_name);
for(String s : starry){
  //do stuff
}
```

And just for clarity, your arrays.xml files should be formatted as:

```
<string-array name="activity_list_menu">
    <item>Profile</item>
    <item>Help</item>
    <item>Legal</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: not what i was looking for. i do not need to loop over ONE array from array.xml i need to loop over array.xml to get all arrays in array.xml.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way you can do that. You'll have to pull each array manually by name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
String array_navigation[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array_xml);


        for (int i = 0; i < array_navigation.length; i++) {
            RandomPicture randomPicture = new RandomPicture(array_navigation[i]);
            adapter.add(randomPicture)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
<string-array name="SomeArrayValues">
       <item>{"name1":val, "name2":val, "name3": val}</item>
       <item>{"name1":val, "name2":val, "name3": val}</item>
       <item>{"name1":val, "name2":val, "name3": val}</item>
</string-array> 



String[] str = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SomeArrayValues);

    for(String s : str){
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject( s );
            System.out.println("*** " + obj.getString( "name1" ));
            System.out.println("*** " + obj.getString( "name2" ));
            System.out.println("*** " + obj.getString( "name3" ));
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```